# How to run a console application without showing the console window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have written an application with the following sub main:

```
 Public Sub Main()
  Dim Value As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
  Dim F As Form
  Select Case Value.Last.ToLower
    Case "-character"
      F = New frmCharacterSheet
    Case "-viewer"
      F = New frmClient
    Case Else
      F = New frmCombat
  End Select
  Application.Run(F)
End Sub
```

This is because I want to be able to install my app with three different startup modes based on the command line. I did have a form that did this, but this has made error trapping very hard because the main form just reports the error.

This console seems to work well but I don't want the user to see the black console screen at startup.

I have searched for the answer but most solutions are 'switch back to a windows forms application'. I don't want to do this though for the above reason. (I cannot use application.run(f) in a winforms start situation because I get a threading error.

I need to know either how to hide the console window, or alternatively how to code a main menu that will launch one of the other three forms (but making them the startup form).

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Elaborate on `I get a threading error`

Comment: http://0.tqn.com/d/visualbasic/1/0/_/Z/formappclass-2.gif

Comment: The above is 'starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation' which is what I get when it is a winforms app but not when a console or service one.

Comment: Right, but see my answer below. It is possible if you are starting it from a different message loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"or alternatively how to code a main menu that will launch one of the other three forms (but making them the startup form)."

Start with a standard **WinForms** Project and use the [Application.Startup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4zch4d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event.  From there you can check your startup parameters and then dynamically **change** the Startup form by assigning your desired instance to "My.Application.MainForm".  This will cause that form to load as if it was the one originally assigned to the "Startup Form" entry.

Click on Project --> Properties --> Application Tab --> "View Application Events" Button (bottom right; scroll down).
Change the Left dropdown from "(General)" to "(MyApplication Events)".
Change the Right dropdown from "Declarations" to "Startup".

Simplified code:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            If True Then
                My.Application.MainForm = New Form1 ' <-- pass your desired instance to MainForm
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: That's great it works really well. I have discovered that changing the application type to 'service' also works, but then ran into some layout problems and so I will be using your excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
Private Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Auto Function GetConsoleWindow Lib "kernel32.dll" () As IntPtr
Private Const SW_HIDE As Integer = 0

Sub Main()
    Dim hWndConsole As IntPtr
    hWndConsole = GetConsoleWindow()
    ShowWindow(hWndConsole, SW_HIDE)
    'continue your code
End Sub
```

It has a side effect that the window will be shown and then immediately hidden

valter

Comment: Again, I think that making it a windows service type is better since the window will never show that way. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I could not use the other solutions as i have no IDE and program from notepad. Therefore I could not change the project properties, it's always a console Application . This answer most closely answer the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to `Project Properties> Application> Application Type>` and select `Windows Forms Application`

At this point your `ConsoleApplication` turns totally invisible, with no User-Interface.

Comment: This would work except that it requires it not to be a forms application for the application.run command I specified in my original question. However I have discovered that changing the application type to 'windows service' does work. I prefer Idle Mind's answer though because then it can stay as a winforms application.

Comment: @Tim that's not entirely true about Application.Run in WinForms. You can use Application.Run on a new thread

Comment: Excellent answer! Also delete unneeded references. Only system.windows.forms needed beyond what console type has.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add another solution although Idle_Mind has already provided an excellent one. This demonstrates that you can use `Application.Run(Form)` inside a WinForms app.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Shared applicationThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main)

    Private Shared Sub Main()
        Dim myForm As Form
        Dim config = 2 ' if 3, will run Form3
        Select Case config
            Case 2
                myForm = New Form2
            Case 3
                myForm = New Form3
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Bad config!")
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        Application.Run(myForm)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        applicationThread.Start()
        ' immediately dispose Form1 so it's not even shown
        Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```